# Select Query with OOP PHP ORM

Tags: php, mysql, oop, orm

for a customer I have to make little adjustments to an application what is build on OOP PHP. I have no experience at all with OOP, and normally I only use PHP for small functions. I would like to select data from my database, to use it in a build function and variable. My code under will explain

```
    public function readTwitter(){

    $accounts = array();
    $hastags = array('coldplay');

    \ORM::for_table('feed_items')->where('portal_reference', 'tw')->delete_many();

    foreach($accounts as $account) {
        $feed = $this->twitter->getFeedByAccount($account);

        foreach($feed as $post){
            $this->twitter->savePost($post);
        }
    }

    foreach($hastags as $hashtag) {
        $feed = $this->twitter->getFeedByHashtag($hashtag);

        foreach($feed->statuses as $post){
            $this->twitter->savePost($post);
        }
    }
}
```

So in this version of the application the foreach loop will check if the var is filled in, what is now done with an array, and use it in the function `readTwitter()` What I like to have is a select query which selects one specific row out of my database to use it instead of an array, written in my application as OOP as follow (written in procedural php):

```
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "database");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `location` = 'wall' ORDER BY `questions`.`id` DESC ";

$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
if ($query) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

$hashtags = $row[2]; //instead of array('coldplay');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function readTwitter(){

    $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "database");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `vragen` WHERE `location` = 'wall' ORDER BY `vragen`.`id` DESC ";

    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    if ($query) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

    $accounts = $row[3];
    $hashtags = $row[2];

    \ORM::for_table('feed_items')->where('portal_reference', 'tw')->delete_many();


        $feed = $this->twitter->getFeedByAccount($accounts);

        foreach($feed as $post){
            $this->twitter->savePost($post);
        }


        $feed = $this->twitter->getFeedByHashtag($hashtags);

        foreach($feed->statuses as $post){
            $this->twitter->savePost($post);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to combine the code and it works like I want, but I dont think this is the right way for OOP, right?